# Is dual wielding as a ranger a good idea? Will it interfere with spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger

I'm making a ranger and I want him to be a dual wielder. But bc both my hands are occupied does that mean I can't cast any spells with m or s components without using an action to put away my sword and draw my component pouch?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, the linked question is about Eldritch Knights, not rangers, but the issue is still the same - dual wielding as a spellcaster.